# dagger recyclerview layoutmanager injection

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to inject recyclerview layoutmanager using dagger from a fragment, problem is when i backstack to fragment containing that injection i got an error cause to layoutmanager already being used by another recyclerview. Actually leaving fragment destroy fragment view and gettting back to it recreate only fragment view and not fragment instance itself so layout manager injection is still the same instance. Here is my code to make things clearer:

From Activity module:

```java
@PerFragment
@ContributesAndroidInjector( modules = ProductListFragmentModule.class )
abstract ProductListFragment contributeProductListFragment( );
```

ProductListFragmentModule dagger module

```java
@Provides
@PerFragment
public static RecyclerView.LayoutManager provideProductListLayoutManager(
        @ActivityContext Context context,
        FlexibleAdapter< AbstractFlexibleItem< ? extends BaseViewHolder > > flexibleAdapter )
{
    int totalSpanSize = 6;
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager( context,
                                                                 totalSpanSize,
                                                                 LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                                                                 false );

    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup( new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup( )
    {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize( int position )
        {
            IFlexible item = flexibleAdapter.getItem( position );

            if( item != null && item instanceof GridLayoutItem )
                return ( ( GridLayoutItem ) item ).getSpanSize( totalSpanSize );

            return totalSpanSize;
        }
    } );

    return gridLayoutManager;
}
```

From ProductListFragment class :

```java
@BindView( R.id.list )
RecyclerView mList;
@Inject
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

...


@Override
public void onActivityCreated( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
     mList.setLayoutManager( mLayoutManager );
}
```

So as i said first time fragment is created no problem but when leaving fragment and getting back (using backstack), got that error about layoutmanager being already attached to a recyclerview.

I'd like to keep layoutmanager injection and avoid creating instance from my fragment, is there anyway to do so? I was thinking about having a dagger scope per fragment **view** along with standard per activity / per fragment scope, but can't figure out how to do so.

Thx for any advices.

Comment: Can you show how are you managing `@PerFragment` annotated component?

Comment: I edited my post and added "From Activity module" code, FYI i 'm using dagger 2.11 and @ContributesAndroidInjector to create subcomponent automatically

Comment: I see, but how do you actually ensure, that `@PerFragment` scoped objects would be fragment-wide singleton? Where do you take advantage of managing that component lifetime? Do you expect `@PerFragment` magically work for you?

Comment: Hum i'n not sure how it works exactly, just followed some tutorials and dunno how it works under the  hood of dagger. But i know it works since my injection give me a new instance for each new fragment

Comment: I guess `onActivityCreated` gets called multiple times and it would work if you'd move it to `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, or `onViewCreated` instead (which gets called once per lifecycle)

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem with injection into fragments inside ViewPager. One of the solutions that worked for me may be applicable to your case.

Remove @PerFragment annotation from the module to ensure that new instance of LayoutManager will be created whenever requested:

```
@Provides
public static RecyclerView.LayoutManager provideProductListLayoutManager() {...}
```

Inject the provider of RecyclerView.LayoutManager instead of the instance:

```
@Inject
Provider<RecyclerView.LayoutManager> mLayoutManager;
```

Instantiate the layout manager using the provider every time the fragment is attached:

```
mList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager.get());
```

The problem i was facing with ViewPager was solved simply by using FragmentStatePagerAdapter instaed of FragmentPagerAdapter

This boils down to not having fragment instances cached and making sure that onCreateView is only called once per Fragment lifespan.